# AWS S3 rejecting deleteDirectory() request even though delete() works

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, laravel-5, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I'm on a Laravel 5.4 project, and in my composer.json file I'm using the following dependencies:

```
"league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3": "~1.0",
"aws/aws-sdk-php-laravel": "3.*",
```

When I try running the below, everything works fine:

```
Storage::disk('s3')->delete('exports/a_few_subdirectories/file.xls');
```

However, when I try running this line of code in an Artisan command, I get the below error:

```
Storage::disk('s3')->deleteDirectory('exports');
```

Here is the error message I receive:

```
Aws\S3\Exception\S3Exception Error executing "DeleteObjects" on "https://mybucket.s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/?delete"; AWS HTTP error: Client error: `POST https://mybucket.s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/?delete` resulted in a `400 Bad Request` response:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Error><Code>MalformedXML</Code><Message>The XML you provided was not well-formed (truncated...)
 MalformedXML (client): The XML you provided was not well-formed or did not validate against our published schema - <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

After googling around, I found a couple of users who had this same error for significantly different reasons. One user said they had hit a 1,000 key limit, and another user said they were missing a required parameter in their post request, but these users were both using Ruby and not Laravel.  Since I'm using these composer packages, I'm assuming the packages are working correctly, and it also seems like everything on S3 is set up correctly (permissions and security settings, for instance).  Another fun fact is that I can successfully use `deleteDirectory` with the local driver instead of the S3 driver, so `deleteDirectory` is working in that instance.

Any ideas as to what might be amiss?  I'd rather delete the directory than loop through files and delete them one by one on S3.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: How many keys *are* you deleting? Hundreds/thousands?

Comment: It was under 1,000 at first, but since it failed to delete it grew to be over 1,000.  We currently have a loop in place that deletes the files one by one instead of trying to delete the whole directory at once.  However, it would still be nice to know if there's a way to use deleteDirectory.

Comment: I suspect you've hit this issue: "The Multi-Object Delete request contains a list of up to 1000 keys that you want to delete." https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/multiobjectdeleteapi.html

Comment: I don't think so because I'm 90% certain we were only trying to delete about 300/month, as long as a "key" is simply an item on S3.  It wasn't until a few months had passed that we noticed these were piling up instead of being deleted, and at this point it had just cracked the 1,000 mark.  However, I can verify if deleteDirectory works on a directory with fewer items in it when I get a chance and I'll let you know the results.